# Optimize command yum

Tags: fedora, performance, yum

I would like knowing if there is a way to  increase the performance of the command `yum` to install and search packages.

I'm a very happy new user of Fedora 16.

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem you're experiencing?  Is it slow to download packages or slow to install?

If the download is taking too long you might want to try the presto (yum-presto) plugin.

See [4.4.3. Plugin Descriptions](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Plugin_Descriptions.html) for a list of available plugins.

If it's the installation itself that's slow you might want to disable any plugin you don't need but I doubt that will make a big difference.

Other than that you will have to look into improving overal system performance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Yum caching.
http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Core/5/html-single/Software_Management_Guide/#sn-yum-caching

Caches provide three advantages:

- The performance of yum increases
- You may carry out yum operations without a network connection, by using only the caches
- You may copy packages from the caches and reuse them elsewhere

  Source: fedoraproject.org.